# List not populating while debugging until opened

Tags: c#, list, debugging

All of the data is in our C# web application is structured in a tree format. Every class that we have extends this base class BaseObject which itself has a list of BaseObjects named Children. We have defined:

```
public List<BaseObject>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return Children.GetEnumerator();
}
```

So in many places in our code we search through the tree with something like:

```
foreach (var rule in this) {
    //do stuff
}
```

When debugging, this foreach loop is skipped in certain parts of the code because it says "this" has no children. If I put a breakpoint before the loop and open up "this" and open up its list of children, then and only then will it go into the foreach loop.

Does anyone have any reason why this might be happening? It is driving me insane.

Comment: Are they always the same parts of the code where this happens?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Do you use Linq somewhere along the way?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the delayed behavior of the Linq operations, and when you force the debugger to show the results, its processes the linq and then show the correct values. Try putting a .ToList() before the foreach.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Yes, it is always the same parts of the code but I can't see any indication as to why it is happening on those parts but not others.

Comment: The correct name is "Deferred Execution"

Comment: @ZWand19: Neither can I, because you post minimal code; however if it's always in the same places, I'd look into that further. It could be due to lazy loading; also in a web application, if you have static properties anywhere storing these instances, it could be a race condition of some sort which putting a breakpoint alleviates. Many variables that are hard to identify seeing only a small part of the code.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but sometimes the debugger will trigger a getter that will actually modify the object (like if private variable is null, create the object and return that). I have seen issues like this before because of that.

Comment: @ansible how would I go about checking if that is what is happening? Is there any way to fix that issue?

Comment: @ZWand19 - There is not sure fire way, but looking at your getters to see if they are doing any sort of loading would be a good idea. Also checking for race conditions like other mentioned. Once you find the problem, you just make sure the data is loaded correctly.  Good luck.

Comment: Possibly throwing an error further along in the code and you only see it when debugging, because it hasn't reached the error yet?

Comment: Per what @Guilherme said, did you try doing the .ToList()? That is almost certainly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the data to be pulled into memory by calling ToList() on your enumeration before iterating through the list, as @Guilherme mentioned in the comments.

It's due to LINQ deferring the SQL execution.

Check out this article by Charlie Calvert for more about LINQ and Deferred Execution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx